# How to plot histogram groups of dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe of bins of page views in a specific site and the quantity of users in each bin a their share of users. It looks like that:

| index | 0-100 | 100-200 | 200-300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| usersquantity | 100 | 100 | 300 |
| usershare | 20 | 20 | 60 |

I am trying to plot a histogram of user quantity:

```
plt.hist(df.iloc[0], bins=[0,100,200,300])
```

But I get this error:

```
cannot determine next label for type <class 'str'>
```

I assume that this is because the index is categorical.

How can I fix this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that, you are trying to use `userquantity` as a column.
If you want to print histogram for `userquantity` row, then you can do this. See further comments inline

```
#Delete the index column as it is text.
df_new = df.drop('index', axis=1)
#Use iloc to get the values from row 'userquantity'
plt.hist(df_new.iloc[0], bins=[0,100,200,300])
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I try tu run this:  df_new = df.drop('index', axis=1) I get an error: ‘<׳ not supported between instances of ‘int’ and ‘str’

Comment: @Vic : Check the column name of yours. Is it exactly `index'` or does it have any spaces. If you give the column name correctly, drop should work.

Comment: @Vic: I have a suspicion, please check the line number where you are seeing the error message, is it on the line where you are dropping the column? or is it some where else?